# vb.net split string group

Tags: .net, regex, xml, vb.net

XML FILE
this is example file, there is 2 group
(real file has more than 1000 group)

```
 <Text>You guys were the ones calling
    out and making a racket.</Text>
  
 <Text>I thought you needed help,</Text>
```

i want them like this in vb
if more than 2 group it will be create new textbox automatically for every group

```
[textbox1]
You guys were the ones calling
out and making a racket.

[textbox2]
I thought you needed help,
```

I think I have to find text by <Text*> tag
and split them but it's duplicated tag I can't define them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is XML then use XML.  Here I've used XElement, LINQ, and XML literals. Hope you get some ideas from this.

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    'for production
    'xe = XElement.Load("put path here")

    'for test
    xe = <Subtitles>
             <Subtitle>
                 <Number>1</Number>
                 <Start>00:00:00,000</Start>
                 <End>00:00:02,236</End>
                 <Duration>2,236</Duration>
                 <Text>You guys were the ones calling
out and making a racket.</Text>
             </Subtitle>
             <Subtitle>
                 <Number>2</Number>
                 <Start>00:00:02,238</Start>
                 <End>00:00:03,343</End>
                 <Duration>1,105</Duration>
                 <Text>I thought you needed help,</Text>
             </Subtitle>
         </Subtitles>

    RichTextBox1.Text = (From el In xe...<Number>
                          Where el.Value = "1").FirstOrDefault.Parent.<Text>.Value

    ''or for 2

    'RichTextBox1.Text = (From el In xe...<Number>
    '                      Where el.Value = "2").FirstOrDefault.Parent.<Text>.Value

    RichTextBox1.Clear()
    Dim groups As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    groups = xe...<Subtitle>

    For Each g As XElement In groups
        Dim s As String
        s = String.Format("Num. {0} Start:{1} End:{2}",
                            g.<Number>.Value,
                            g.<Start>.Value,
                            g.<End>.Value)
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(s)
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(ControlChars.Cr)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and it's working fine.
Now I can split any group I want

```
Dim xml = XDocument.Load("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\12.xml")

Dim xstr As String = xml.ToString
Dim String1 As String = "<Text>"
Dim String2 As String = "</Text>"
Dim xlist As New List(Of String)
Do
    xstr = Mid(xstr, InStr(xstr.ToLower, String1.ToLower) + String1.Length)
    xlist.Add(Mid(xstr, 1, InStr(xstr.ToLower, String2.ToLower) - 1))
    xstr = Mid(xstr, InStr(xstr.ToLower, String2.ToLower) + String2.Length)
Loop Until InStr(xstr.ToLower, String1.ToLower) = 0

Dim i = 0

Do
    RichTextBox1.Text &= xlist(i) & Environment.NewLine
    i += 1
Loop Until i = xlist.Count
```

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>